# Open CKEDITOR with a default code in the source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR for a new page in my CMS panel, which replaces textarea that contains a table.
I want CKEDITOR to open with a source code that I will set.
I mean each time CKEDITOR will launch, it will be with a source code inside and not empty.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/Main_Page)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Numerous ways to do this , html markup in page, set textarea value before editor initializes, set data in textarea...non are hard to research

Answer (score 0):

First of all in Your config.js add

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

And in your text area

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="question" name="question">{{$default_code}}</textarea>
```

It should work.